# Write a method to take in a number and return an array containing all numbers less than number that are divisible by 3 or 5 but not both?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to create a method that will result in an array of integers that are divisible by 3 or 5 but not both. I'd like to use for loop. I can't seem to get this to work:

```
def divizthreefive(max):
    yes = []

    for x in list(range(max)):
        if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
            yes.append(x)
        if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
            yes.remove(x)


print(divizthreefive(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def divizthreefive(max):
    yes = []

    for x in range(max):
        if (x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0) and (x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0):
            yes.append(x)
    return yes


print((divizthreefive(20)))
```

I forgot to add a return at the end. Simple solution.

Comment: Also, I removed list() in front of range on the 4th line.

Comment: Change the 'if' statement to include !=0 for %3 and %5. This method takes shorter amount of time to run than the one originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need the return statement, but you also need to amend the second if to elif, and change the action as follows.

```
def divizthreefive(max):
    yes = []

    for x in list(range(max)):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 != 0:
            yes.append(x)
        elif x % 5 == 0 and x % 3 != 0:
            yes.append(x)
    return yes

print(divizthreefive(20))
```

Why remove something that hasn't been added to the new array?

What you were trying to do with your code, is add the numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 to the array, and then go through the new array and remove the integers that are divisible by both 5 and 3.

Comment: I see what you're saying.

I believe, `if (x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0) and (x % 3 != 0 or x % 5 != 0):`, will also work. I left the append and remove methods as the time it took to run the program was shorter. However, now that I run it again, it looks like the method I just added in this reply takes less time. Thanks!